# Photoshop bug or something using drop shadow

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have several layers using drop shadow that is suppose to have different angles. But whenever I change or add a drop shadow all others gets changed too, to the same angle.

Is this a bug or is there an option to stop this very annoying behavior?

Comment: Which Photoshop version are you using? What's your operating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you enable global lighting? If you did, a change to one light source will change all of them. Be sure that any drop shadows you create are independent of one another by unchecking the global lighting option: Layer effects > drop shadow > disable global lighting.

Comment: So thats what that option does :D I've wondered for over 5 years x)

Comment: I'm glad this resolved your issue! Happy 'shopping!

Comment: If you came here because you were directed here for an answer to a non-novice issue, then you are just as disappointed as I am right now.  It is impossible to find information about real bugs when 90% of the posts aren't about bugs but just inexperience. Please don't label your question bug if it is not a confirmed bug but a confirmed not-bug. Unless of course you enjoy wasting thousands of people's time.